# Unable to connect to MySQL from PHP : "mysql_connect(): No such file or directory"

Tags: macos, php, mysql

I'm not able connect to mysql via php. It produces `[error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): No such file or directory` error message in apache error log when executing `mysql_connect()` function in PHP.

Please find the warning messages when running `php -m` command:

```
$ php -m | grep mysql  
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/msql.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/msql.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_mysql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_mysql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_mysqli.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_mysqli.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
pdo_mysql
```

and

```
$ mysqladmin -h `hostname` --port=3306 version
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'heapzero.local' failederror: 'Host '192.168.1.36' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server'
```

PHP Version:

```
$ php --version
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/msql.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/msql.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_mysql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_mysql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_mysqli.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_mysqli.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.3.2 (cli) (built: Aug  7 2010 00:04:41) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

MySQL Version:

```
mysql --version
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.50, for apple-darwin10.3.0 (i386) using readline 5.1
```

I've spent lot of time in trying to fix this. Please suggest! Thanks!

Comment: @heapzero - This probably is better asked on Stack Overflow.  I am voting to move it there, please do NOT repost it, it should get transferred if others agree to migrate.

Comment: What exact platform is this on? How have you installed MySQL? `$ mysqladmin -h \`hostname\` --port=3306 version` works fine for me on Snow Leopard, but I appear to have a lower version of MySQL than you (5.0.51), though I'm on the latest OSX (10.6.4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem could be related to "remote access". You should try editing the configuration of mysql. The file may be called my.cnf.

Here is a link that may be helpful:
http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/remotemysql.htm

Answer (score 8):

If you use Mac OS X Lion, try changing the server/host name to IP address instead.
Example: instead of `localhost`, use `127.0.0.1` in the PHP code.

Comment: It also happened with me when using lampp, it looks that it was some kind of conflict with the Unix socket used by lampp and the one used by the distribution mysql